# Is is possible to extract aspect values from raster based on vector point locations?

Tags: qgis, point, aspect

Looking for ideas on a workflow in QGIS:

I have an Aspect raster layer and a point vector layer from the same area. Such point data represents localities of interest for a particular study. Is there any way I can obtain the exact Aspect value at each of those points? I know I could always use the Information tool and click on each point to get that information, but that would imply a lot of manual work and it would be error-prone.

I was looking for a more authomated (and elegant) way of doing it - either using a single tool or a sequence of tools/commands. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the [point sampling plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/). You load your point and raster layers, and the tool samples the raster values at each point, creating a new layer.

Of course this only samples the cell value. Are you looking to interpolate within the cell?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I eventually found that same tool and tried it out, but I've got no results. I've tested it using both a DEM and an aspect raster. With the DEM it worked fine, but when I tried it with the Aspect raster, the field (in the new shapefile generated by the plugin) containing the information from the raster had "Null" in all point records...

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Actually found the problem right now after a new test... My point vector layer was not in the same SRC than the raster - OTF was stoping me from notice it right away.

So, the plugin works fine! I'm now gonna try the same process using SAGA via processing toolbox, just to see if it works also!

Once again, many thanks!

Comment: I can't find the "add grid value" command in the porcessing toolbox. Was it removed/discontinued? I have other SAGA commands available, but not that one...

Comment: I'm not really familiar enough with the SAGA interface to comment on that. Maybe ask a new question about SAGA if it hasn't been answered already.

Comment: Thanks for your availability - I'm refering to the processing toolbox inside QGIS, that allows us to use SAGA functions (as well as functions from other providers). I didn't mean actually using the SAGA interface. But nevertheless your first suggestion was spot on!

Comment: Heh, I actually meant to ask a question on Stack. I don't have enough experience with the SAGA/QGIS interfaces. (Also, comments are considered the wrong place for new questions.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "add raster values to points" from the SAGA GIS tools and if you want to automate it you can use the batch processing option that is in the upper right corner of the window.

The image is in French but you will get an idea.

[image]

Comment: hadn't seen that before! There's also **v.sample** in GRASS... would be interesting to compare the speeds of these 3 methods :)